# Refresh Navigation View in eclipse application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to Refresh Navigation View in eclipse application. The project explorer in the eclipse application does not show the projects , untill it is refreshed or right clicked on it. How to refresh it programmatically? And where to put this code?

Comment: Are you creating files or folders from a plugin?

Comment: i am creating a project inside. When i create its visible, but after restart the project is not visible until i click on explorer.
I found that we need to add:
`@Override
  public IWorkspaceRoot getDefaultPageInput(){
   return ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
  }`
in WorkbenchAdvisor.java, but adding this gives null pointer at many places in WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply @greg-449. refreshLocal is useful, but i was missing a small piece of code and refrshing was not needed. Eventually i figured out the answer. I had to ovverride a function as I mentioned in one of my comments. I was trying to use the getDefaultPageInput in a wrong way and hence i was getting errors. Eventually i removed the erroneous code in my project and added following to WorkbenchAdvisor.java

```
@Override 
public IWorkspaceRoot getDefaultPageInput()
{ 
    return ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If at all possible you should use the `create` methods of `org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile` and `IFolder` to create files and folders.

If that is not possible use the `refreshLocal` method of `IProject` or `IFolder` to update the workspace.

All these calls will generate one or more `IResourceChangeEvent` events which will be seen by views and anything else that needs to know about resource changes. The view will update automatically when it sees these events.

To reduce the number of resource change events generated enclose your modifications in a `WorkspaceJob` or `WorkspaceModifyOperation` or `IWorkspaceRunnable`.